# Do scriptures allow men to perform last rites for relatives that are still alive?

Tags: marriage, women, smriti, sraddha, samskara

According to [this](https://www.news18.com/news/buzz/150-men-from-across-the-country-took-a-dip-in-the-ganga-to-let-go-of-their-evil-wives-toxic-feminism-1857573.html) news report, a group of Indian men decided to perform last rites for their former wives.

> They say taking a dip in the Ganga redeems you of all your sins. But a group of Indian men decided that taking a dip in the river, that's considered sacred by Hindus, will help the world get rid of 'toxic feminism'. So, they did exactly that. Last week, 150 odd men from across the country packed their bags and left for Varanasi, in Uttar Pradesh.
>
> ...
>
> **These 'harassed' men did a 'shraadha' (last rites) for their alive wives** who don't live with them anymore. They also conducted a 'pishachini mukti puja' for their former wives – in order to get rid of the 'bad memory of past marital relationships'.

Do scriptures allow śrāddha to be performed for relatives when they are still alive?

Comment: Yes. Shraddha is done when a man takes sanyasa - the wife and child do last rites because he is symbolically dead to them/society/world. Scriptures allow performing shraddha even for yourself (like in the case you don't have any progeny who can do last rites for you after death)

Comment: Looks like they did to show their hatred towards them. Only time to perform shraddha for living people is when he takes Sannyasa. He is symbolically dead and leaves all relationships then and there.

Comment: I guess there is also an instance when Prajapati Daksha wanted to perform shraadha of Sati after she married to Shiv, against his wishes and he wanted to eliminate her from his life entirely.

Comment: yes. sadhus do as part of their initiation into sannyas.

Comment: I think you already know about the Sannyasis's last rites being performed while he is still alive.. So do you want answers only for persons other than Sannyasis?

Comment: @Rickross Yes, I'm more interested in men doing last rites for relatives i.e., _others_, not 'atma shraddha' which a sannyasi does for self.